# Nodes can't connect to server after bootstrap

Tags: maas

I installed maas and I was able to add nodes and they became in ready state.

I executed:

```
juju bootstrap
```

And then one of my nodes is waking up and I receive this message on server (after `juju status`):

[image: juju status]

And this message is shown on node after it wakes up:

[image: cloud-init]

I am doing this several times and each time I receive the same result.

I think something is wrong with my network. It look like this:

```
internet <-> router <-> switch <-> nodes
                |
                |<----->server
```

Router is used as a DHCP Server. It's ip is 192.168.0.1 - it's my default gateway.
When I was installing maas server I installed dnsmasq and I have used as a range  192.168.0.5-192.158.0.200 and for gateway I used 192.168.0.1 and for domain I used nothing. I was able to add nodes without problems.

What maybe the problem not letting nodes to connect to maas server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acctualy I get errors it was fault of old ubuntu instance. I reinstall ubuntu server but not nodes so I recieve those errors. After first bootrstrap must be done installation.

Answer (score 1):

The nodes are trying to contact 192.168.0.101 which they think is the maas server.  However your question said that it's not on that address.  Is your DEFAULT_MAAS_URL configured properly in /etc/maas/maas_local_settings.py ?

Also if using .local as a domain it requires mDNS (i.e. Avahi) to work across the LAN, so I wonder if your broadcast traffic is working as it should be?

Comment: But my server has ip adress 192.168.0.101 and in /etc/maas/maas_local_settings.py is everything all right. I don't use any domains. I have internet on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, is the time on your node within 30 minutes or so of the server's?  If not use the BIOS screen to set it.  If the time is far out it prevents Oauth from working.